# How to get rid of backslashes in nested json

Tags: python, json, regex, python-requests

I make a request to a backend API and get the data back in json format

The response looks something like this. Kindly note that the body key values will be different and there are over 100's of them. The data1.json looks like this

```
[
    {
        "body": "[{\"task_ids\":[],\"accounts\":[],\"entity_ids\":[12814],\"guid\":\"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448\",\"id\":\"0034030fb97251b3\",\"subject\":\"Uploaded Application\"}]",
        code": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "msg": "OK",
        "name": "0"
    },
   {
        "body": "[{\"task_ids\":[],\"accounts\":[],\"entity_ids\":[12814],\"guid\":\"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448\",\"id\":\"0034030fb97251b3\",\"subject\":\"Uploaded Application\",\}]",
        code": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "msg": "OK",
        "name": "0"
    },

...
]
```

I need to get rid of the

1. "\"  in all of the body key in the json response
2. Concatenate the key[body'] into one array

ideally it should look something like this.

```
[
  {"body":"[{"task_ids":[],"accounts":[],"entity_ids":[12814],"guid":"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448","id":"0034030fb97251b3","subject":"Uploaded Application",]","[{"task_ids":[],"accounts":[],"entity_ids":[12814],"guid":"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448","id":"0034030fb97251b3","subject":"Uploaded Application",]",..}


]
```

I have tried replace and a lot of methods but none of them are replacing the \ so I cannot even go to step 2. What I did find out was if I save it to a text file the backslashes are replaced but then I cannot again send the response back as a json object. The code to get the data1.json file so far looks like this.

```
data = json.loads(r.text)


with open('data1.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4,
               ensure_ascii = False)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the first points as in my desired output? Thanks.

Comment: It's just a JSON string encoded as a value in *another* JSON string. Run it through the `body` parameter through `json.loads` again

Comment: can you give an example @ceejayoz

Comment: I don't work in Python, but something like `data.body = json.loads(data.body)` is probably what you want.

Comment: @davedwards I use requests not urlib, as in the example

Comment: @ceejayoz it gives me errors, but thanks I got an idea

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood Is that the actual response object? There's a syntax error because `code": 200` lacks opening double quotes `"`?

Comment: @FailSafe it is. I donot know why but this is what the response returns

Comment: ```<class 'requests.models.Response'>``` it shows this @FailSafe

Comment: @FailSafe ```data = json.loads(r.text)``` returns a list object

Comment: @FailSafe I have edited it it does end with a }

Comment: @FailSafe it does, I made a mistake since the body value was very long

Comment: @ShadmanMahmood You're not copying and pasting them to your post on StackOverFlow? BTW, the second dictionary `body` object is also flawed.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(For starters, what you gave is invalid JSON, and `json` will either fail to parse it completely or produce something bogus. You need to make sure you extract the response correctly, and if this is really what the response is, have the sending party fix it.)

Now, about the question as asked:</sub>

---

You don't need to do anything special. That's just how JSON represents values that themselves contain JSON's special characters ("escapes" them with a backslash).

If you load the data via a proper JSON parser (e.g. `json.loads()`), it will undo that escaping, and in e.g. `data[0]['body']`, you will see proper data.

Of course, since that string is JSON itself, you will need to further parse it with `json`, too, if you need to split it into its meaningful parts...

Comment: Not currently. The 2nd `body` object is still flawed. It's closing is literally `,\\}]`. Secondly, the `code` object lacks double quotes `"` We've been editing/updating the post for the last half hour. This requires more processing especially if it has 100s of responses.

Comment: @FailSafe Then the input the OP gave is just invalid JSON and `json` will probably fail to parse it. I assumed that's irrelevant to OP's question as asked 'cuz they didn't mention any parse errors or _completely_ bogus data.

Comment: And that's what I was on about above. It "technically" wouldn't be relevant, but if this is the actual API response, it can't be processed by JSON.loads() without more processing. Then we have the further problem of not knowing what the rest of the responses look like if the current ones are so flawed, so we can't predict what other problems they'll have.

Comment: @FailSafe Okay, I added a note to this effect. SO is supposed to teach _best_ practices, so I'm _not_ going to advise a newbie to duct-tape a broken response. Any such code will only work until the sending party breaks (or fixes) something else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data is incorrectly formatted and invalid JSON (missing quotes in "key" strings (e.g. `code": 200,`), invalid syntax in second dictionary body object, as [mentioned in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802889/how-to-get-rid-of-backslashes-in-nested-json?noredirect=1#comment98275215_55802889) (e.g. `"Uploaded Application\",\}]"`)).

However, after fixing these, a simple `str.replace()` statement can be used to get the expected JSON format.  Then, simply parse the JSON content and build the desired list:

```
import json

data = '''[
    {
        "body": "[{\"task_ids\":[],\"accounts\":[],\"entity_ids\":[12814],\"guid\":\"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448\",\"id\":\"0034030fb97251b3\",\"subject\":\"Uploaded Application\"}]",
        "code": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "msg": "OK",
        "name": "0"
    },
   {
        "body": "[{\"task_ids\":[],\"accounts\":[],\"entity_ids\":[12814],\"guid\":\"2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448\",\"id\":\"0034030fb97251b3\",\"subject\":\"Uploaded Application\"}]",
        "code": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "msg": "OK",
        "name": "0"
    }
]'''

r = json.loads(data.replace('\\', '').replace('"[', "[").replace("]\"", "]"))

l = []

for d in r:
    l.append(d)
```

Now inspect the contents of `l`:

```
>>> l
[{u'body': [{u'entity_ids': [12814], u'accounts': [], u'task_ids': [], u'guid': u'2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448', u'id': u'0034030fb97251b3', u'subject': u'Uploaded Application'}], u'headers': {u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, u'code': 200, u'name': u'0', u'msg': u'OK'}, 
{u'body': [{u'entity_ids': [12814], u'accounts': [], u'task_ids': [], u'guid': u'2DFEB337-5F5D-4DF5-84CF-E951D237D448', u'id': u'0034030fb97251b3', u'subject': u'Uploaded Application'}], u'headers': {u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, u'code': 200, u'name': u'0', u'msg': u'OK'}]
```